# How to configure groovydoc (for gradle) to generate documentation for both java and groovy source

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, javadoc, groovydoc

The documentation for the groovy doc task ([see link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Groovydoc.html)) states:

> Generates HTML API documentation for Groovy source, and optionally, Java source

But the rest of the documentation does not explain how to optionally generate the documentation for java source. I have a mixed project (both java and groovy) and I would like to generate a single javadoc jar file for both instead of 2 separate jar files. So how do I configure groovydoc to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like doing this:

```
groovydoc {
  source project.tasks.findByName('javadoc').source
}
```

properly adds the java only classes to the groovydoc output.